# Knockout JS, Dynamic UI, Components & ViewModels

Tags: knockout.js

having a bit of a mare with trying to work out how to create a dynamic UI, at runtime, using Knockout 3.4.0 and MVC.

**Requirement:** Integrate SSRS SOAP reporting with an MVC website using knockout js WITHOUT using ReportViewer and dynamically build report filters interface with the parameter data received from the SSRS server.

Approach: I have successfully managed to be able to pragmatically retrieve all parameter data and also create a report with hard coded filters that is displayed in a view using knockout.

**Problem:** Each report will have different filter parameters, such as date from, date to, facility, region, etc. I am struggling to work out how, using knockout, to be able to dynamically build the UI to show each reports filter and also be able to include the filter value dynamically in the root viewmodel for when the filter is posted back to the server.

**Attempts:** I have pragmatically worked out what a given parameter's UI type should be i.e. 'TEXT, BOOLEAN, DROPDOWN, DATETIME etc, and pass that in the inital viewModel which is bound to my view on first load. I have explored the concept of knockout components and have actually managed to create a basic one but I cannot work out how to bind it or retrieve the bound data afterwards.

I have a foreach loop that iterates the parameter collection, checks the UI type, and then will embed a component applicable for it's UI type, such as a datepicker or a dropdown list. Now there can be more that 1 of each type but they need to be uniquely identified so that the different values can be retrieved when data is posted back.

One of my approaches is as below;

```
DropDownList component

ko.components.register("dropDownList", {
viewModel: function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.validValues = ko.observableArray(data.ValidValues);
},

template: "<select data-bind='options: validValues, optionsText: 'Label', optionsValue: 'Value'></options>"
```

});

This is my View, only the 'DROPDOWN' type in this code is currently using a component

```
        <div id="parameters" data-bind="foreach: parameters">
        <!-- ko if: PromptUser() === true && Prompt() !== null && Prompt() !== "" --> @*Only show parameters that should be visible*@
            <!-- ko if: UiType() === 'DATETIME' -->
                <div data-bind="template: { name: 'date-template', data: $data }"></div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: UiType() === 'BOOLEAN' -->
                <div data-bind="template: { name: 'boolean-template', data: $data }"></div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: UiType() === 'TEXT' -->
                <div data-bind="template: { name: 'text-template', data: $data }"></div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: UiType() === 'MULTI' -->
                <div data-bind="template: { name: 'multi-template', data: $data }"></div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: UiType() === 'DROPDOWN' -->
                <div data-bind='component: { name: "dropDownList", params: { data: $data }}'></div>           
            <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
```

As you can imagine, I could 1,2,3 or more dropdown lists, all with different data.

How would I be able to make them unique?
How would I be able to access the selected values?
How components interact with the parent view model?

However my data never gets bound to the component template. I think I have blinded myself by trawling the web too much but there must be a way to do this at run time.

I would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Why you need to "uniquely identify" data from markup? It should be already in your viewModel, automatically updated by bindings, and you know it's schema.

Comment: This is the problem, and why I think knockout is going to fail me here, I do not know beforehand exactly what the markup will be. The components are to be loaded during binding based upon a data type parameter in the collection I am iterating over. These are parameters that are retrieved from an SSRS server so I have lots of information about them but each report will have any number of parameters of differing types and I am hoping to not have code for every single one of them just in case it used or not. May not be possible I suppose.

Comment: why would you want to know markup? In your viewModel you have `parameters`, it's items are automatically updated by bindings. At the end of day you don't look at the DOM, you look at the `parameters` in your viewModel and process it anyway you want (with same set of ifs for example).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the component markup it should look like `<dropDownList params="value: $data"></dropDownList>` (I'm not sure on the value binding in the params, [look over the docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html) and fiddle around with it until it gets binding).